# How to get only field(column) in mailchimp

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp

I am getting fields name with values but i only want to get the fields name in mailchimp:

My controller code:

```
 public function getFieldsListMailchimp(Request $request)
{
    $list_id = $request->input('list_id');
    $user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $apikey = DB::table('user_mlc_mailchimp')->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->value('api_key');
    if ($list_id) {
        $mc = new MailChimp($apikey);
        $fields = $mc->get('/lists/'.$list_id.'/members?fields=members.id,members.email_address,members.merge_fields');
        $fields = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Fields list!', 'dataArray' => $fields];
        return Response::json($fields, 200);

    } else {
        $errorResponse = [
            'message' => 'Lists not found!',
            'error' => '401'
        ];
        return Response::json($errorResponse);
    }
}
```

Output i am getting of this code is :

```
  {

 "status": 1,
"message": "Fields list!",
"dataArray": {
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "663657d6bee76fdd3285c879bf2849e2",
            "email_address": "shahzad.hussain@vaivaltech.com",
            "merge_fields": {
                "FNAME": "shahzad",
                "LNAME": "Hussain"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "b59a741183b7e1990156a46faa29b60c",
            "email_address": "Hello@gmail.com",
            "merge_fields": {
                "FNAME": "Shahzad",
                "LNAME": "Hussain"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As You can see i want to get only fields name that is ( id, email_address, merger_fields( FNAME,LNAME) but here i am getting fields name along with values i only want to get fields name here?
ANy help would be highly appreciated! 
Thanks in advance.

```
        public function getFieldsListMailchimp(Request $request)
{
    $list_id = $request->input('list_id');
    $user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $apikey = DB::table('user_mlc_mailchimp')->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->value('api_key');
    if ($list_id) {
        $mc = new MailChimp($apikey);
        $fields = $mc->get('/lists/'.$list_id.'/members?fields=members.id,members.email_address,members.merge_fields');
        $fields = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Fields list!', 'dataArray' => array_keys($fields)];
        return Response::json($fields, 200);

    } else {
        $errorResponse = [
            'message' => 'Lists not found!',
            'error' => '401'
        ];
        return Response::json($errorResponse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $fields = [
    'status' => 1, 
    'message' => 'Fields list!', 
    'dataArray' => array_keys($fields)
 ]);
 return Response::json($fields, 200);
```

[Array Keys,](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)  will get you the keys only

Comment: when i add array_keys it shown nothing just a message:{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Fields list!",
    "dataArray": [
        "members"
    ]
}

Comment: it does not show any fields name can u please guide me further

Comment: i posted my whole controller code with your answer please see.

Comment: it should display only keys but i dont know why its not displaying

Comment: Any thing else for this issue?

Comment: I actually didn't get your problem, try using `array_keys($fields['members'])`; this will get you the keys from members array. i think this is what you want